# Where can I get help with this Question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my WordPress Development Stack Exchange post: [Problems With WP Bannarize Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313030/problems-with-wp-bannarize-plugin)

I've been trying for days to find a place where I can get this answered and am told it's off topic for here. How can I get help with this issue? Is there a way I can ask my question here without going off topic, or another community other then wordpress.org anyone can suggest where I can ask about this? I've been trying to get this question answered for days and keep getting the moderator runaround and would like to find a way I can just get some help on this.

Comment: You say you got the moderator runaround for several days, but your account has a single question and is less than a day old, do you have another account where this happened?

Comment: If you are a developer, then digging the plugin and solving your problem should not be an issue. Otherwise, I would suggest you hire a developer to resolve the issue quickly.

Comment: @TomJNowell - The moderator runaround started on another community. Fortunately, it was a single mod who made a mistake and another community mod was able to fix it.

Comment: @JackJohansson - I am a developer, but I'm not familiar with wordpress code. Most of my coding experience has been in the backend of Drupal, which tends to use more straightforward code where I can see what each function does, and I find wordpress code hard to follow without learning more about it, as it uses too many external functions that I have to track down in other files to find out what they do.

Comment: @RadiantFreedom totally separate set of moderators then, different stacks have their own community elected moderators and conventions. E.g. 3rd party plugins wouldn't be offtopic on the Physics stack, but your question would get closed for another reason ( nothing to do with Physics I'm guessing )

Answer (score 4):

I feel for you, I really do. However, WPSE is a WordPress development Q&A site, it's not a 3rd party plugin support site. So unfortunately, you'll most likely not get the support from here.

You may try to post it on [StackOverflow under WordPress tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), but the type of support you are asking for, I don't think you'd receive it from there as well.

In the question, you said:

> **This plugin appears to have been abandoned by the developers ...**

If that is the case, then it is a very important sign that means, **you should stop using that plugin on live sites all together.** This is the best time to switch the plugin, even if you hire a developer for a temporary fix.

Without the continuous update and support from the original developers, you'll keep facing similar issues in the future & that will cost you a lot of time and money. So even if the switch is a bit costly now, it'll save you a lot of headache and money in the future.

Comment: I do agree that it's best to use plugins still supported by the developers. The decision isn't mine to make though, I was hired to troubleshoot problems with this site and thought I'd gotten them all, when this one came out of nowhere. I was reaching out to see if there might have been someone who knew a simple fix to keep my client going a while longer but sadly that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Keep in mind we're not a discussion forum, so you need to be able to mark a question as a canonical answer, aka the correct answer for all, rather than the best answer for the current situation